Recover data from HTC One with dead battery
I recently found my old HTC One and wanted to take a look at the pictures on there. To my unpleasant surprise, the battery died and doesn't charge.
I can still plug it in and it shows charging, but it never goes above 0%. If I try to boot it, it just crashes back into the loading screen.
Is there any way I can access the storage from the boot/recovery menu alone?

HTC One was originally release with Android 4.4 so it should be not encrypted which should make things easier. But without a working power supply even a recovery ROM may crash. You can try to connect it to a charger with more power and/or try to open the device and disconnect the dead battery. I was one successful doing so with an old Samsung Atom based tablet.

Try connecting a different cable for a long time to see if it works. Have you backed up your data anywhere like Google Photo/Drive or any external storage device? If not, then you need to opt for Android Data Recovery Software to recover your data that too without rooting it. But for that too, you need to switch on your phone. Also, the model has a non-removable charger so if the idea of a "different cable" doesn't work out, go for a phone repair service.
